# Pythonic way to generate list of tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples

I would like to to get list of all pairs of numbers between 0 and 100:

```
[(0,0), (0,1), (0,2),...,(99,99)]
```

How can I make it in pythonic way? Cause I know, that I can just append needed tuples in two `for` cycles.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is `itertools.product(*iterables)`.

```
import itertools
list(itertools.product((range(100), range(100)))
```

Comment: No problem, itertools has a lot of fun stuff. Does about 95% of what you would ever need in terms of "manipulating" iterators.